# RequestMapping of a path with empty request param

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need to have a single mapping for /jsp/login and /jsp/login?error

Please note I cant use /jsp/login?error=someval and then check if param has that value or default value. = after the param is not allowed in this case.

Is this feasible with spring?

To clarify the above, I already have the code as:

```
@RequestMapping("/jsp/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if(error != null && !error.isEmpty()) {
            model.put("message", "wrong user id or password");
        }
        return "login";
}
```

So both the requests /jsp/login and /jsp/login?error is mapped as error = null as required = false. And  error != null if the url is something like /jsp/login?error=yes

Requirement: error != null even for /jsp/login?error without any value of the parameter

Comment: My bad! changing if(error != null && !error.isEmpty())  to if(error != null)  works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/jsp/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginWindow(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String errorStr) throws LoginException {...}
```

The important part is `required = false`, so if you call the `/jsp/login` errorStr would have value as null.

Comment: Please have a look at edited question, I tried to make it clearer. The question is errorStr should be not null with just the existence of it. With required false, errorStr is null. With ?error=somevalue it's not null. Is there a way to make it not null with just ?error, kind of like boolean

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You can have optional request params.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsp/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String handleLogin(
            HttpServletRequest req,
            @RequestParam(value="error",required = false) String error) {
        //TODO: write your code here
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: That way, by default, param will be required.

Comment: Change to @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error...

Comment: Please have a look at edited question, I tried to make it clearer. The question is errorStr should be not null with just the existence of it. With required false, errorStr is null. With ?error=somevalue it's not null. Is there a way to make it not null with just ?error, kind of like boolean

Answer (score 0):

My bad! changing if(error != null && !error.isEmpty()) to if(error != null) works perfectly. 
Missed the basic.